# WP_Query order by usermeta value

Tags: wordpress, left-join

I have a WP_Query that is working fine, however I now need to amend it to sort by a value from usermeta (in this case the user has a meta_key of 'jobs_order'). This is a numerical value, the idea being I order posts depending on this, for instance an user with a value of 0 will see their posts before the next user that has 1.

I have hooked into it as so:

```
add_filter('posts_join', 'wpa_66507_join');

function wpa_66507_join( $join ) {
    if ( is_page('browse-jobs') && is_main_query() )  {

        global $wpdb;

        // join the usermeta table so we can sort by meta key
        $join .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} AS um ON ( um.user_id = {$wpdb->posts}.post_author AND um.meta_key = 'jobs_order' )";
    }
    return $join;
}
```

And the WP_Query is set to orderby um.meta_value_num ASC. However this isn't working, whether I comment out the join statement or not, the posts remain in the same order. Be very grateful for any ideas on this.

Comment: Hello,As I understand you have to make a post sorting order right?

Comment: Hi, yes that's correct

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'meta_key'   => 'age',
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'age',
            'value'   => array( 3, 4 ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I can order the posts fine, the question I posted is to order by a meta_value of the author/user

Comment: what is your current output?

Comment: Ok, so despite the $args having orderby set to um.met_value, it is sorting by post_date